# "Oestrogen" and "oesophagus" -- why are they spelled differently in British English?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, greek

Within Biology, there are some biological terms that differ in spelling between the British English and American English dictionaries. For example, *oestrogen* and *oesophagus*, as well as the word *oestriol* are all spelled differently in British English dictionaries. Is there anything in particular that makes this so?

Comment: You don't mention of how you spell them in America!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The word *oestrogen* comes from the Latin word *oestrus*, and *oesophagus* is a Latin word as well.

The *oe* spelling in Latin originally represented a diphthong [oj] ("oy"), but then later (in Latin) became a long vowel [ee].  When we borrowed such words into English, it was pronounced more like [i], [e], or [ɛ] (depending on the word), following English pronunciation rules.

And since we pronounce them like "estrogen" and "esophagus", the US English spelling was changed to reflect the English pronunciation more closely, by dropping the *o*.  In British English, the connection to the original Latin spelling was retained.

(Something similar to this happened with, e.g., *encyclopaedia* (British) / *encyclopedia* (US).)

Comment: Right on the money. Historically, English comes from both Germanic and Latin/French roots. This led to wildly inconsistent spellings that were often at odds with pronunciation. From the mid 1800s through the early 1900s, the US had a series of reforms to bring American spelling more in line with real-world phonetic pronunciation. (Even multimillionaire Andrew Carnegie and President Teddy Roosevelt weighed in.) This didn't occur in other English-speaking countries, so that's why you see oestrogen/estrogen, as well as colour/color, catalogue/catalog, and anaemia/anemia.

Comment: Incidentally, written standard German (Hochdeutsch) is quite the opposite. It's phonetically accurate: once you know the rules, you can correctly pronounce any written word. And with a very few quirks, you can correctly spell any word you hear. As I understand it, this is largely due to Martin Luther's translation of the Bible, in which spelling was phonetically consistent, and that standardized the language.

Comment: Hochdeutsch is not phonetically accurate, but it is much more consistent.  However, it is becoming less so, because many English words have been borrowed into German whose English spellings are retained, e.g. *live*, *jeans*, *chatten*... and even *handy*, a German creation that means cell phone, but follows English spelling conventions.  (The proper German spelling would have been *Händi*.)

Comment: Mein Handy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WIscxut_ak (Stephen Fry, QI).

Comment: Actually I find that it happens the other way around - the Americans change their prononcuation to fit their spelling.  I'm British and would pronounce the 'ee' sound for the 'oe/ae' part of oestrogen, oesophagus, and paedophile.  Oh, and encyclopaedia (but the US haven't got round to changing pronunciation there).

Comment: @Bob Murphy, Agreed.  One precision though.  The "color" spelling, along with a large number of other ones can actually be traced back as early as 1783 with the speller ([look here for the 1832 edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=2bEAAAAAYAAJ&dq=webster&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false)) by [Noah Webster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah_Webster) (the father of the Webster dictionary).  In this little book (around 100 million copies sold !!!) one can spot most of the common words spelling variants between AmE and  modern English.

Comment: ***Oesophagus*** was **not** Roman Latin; it was **medieval** Latin from the 12–13ᵗʰ centuries. It comes from ancient Greek *οἰσοϕάγος*, the gullet. The OED3 adds:  ”Compare Middle French *œsophagus* (1549). Compare **oesophage** *n.* If analysed correctly, the formation of ancient Greek *οἰσοϕάγος*  is unusual, as *-ϕάγος* in compounds usually means ‘eating (something)’, ‘eater’.” It appears that ***oestrus*** was classical, though: “classical Latin *oestrus* gadfly, wild desire, frenzy < ancient Greek *οἶστρος* gadfly, insect that infects tunny fish, also sting, hence frenzy, mad impulse.”

Comment: @Jez, Yes we shortened the e in esophagus, estrogen and pedophile, but this had nothing to do with dropping the useless o or a in the spelling, which is why encyclopedia (and pediatrician, by the way) still has a long e in American English.

Answer (score 6):

The person most credited with these systematic changes in American spelling is Noah Webster. He developed and published the first complete American English dictionary about 200 years ago.  He was a believer in spelling according to sound and consequently removed a number of silent letters.  He also changed "s" to "z" in certain words (realise" to "realize" e.g.) And finally, he changed the "-re" ending found in French-derived nouns to "-er". ("theatre"-"theater")

Comment: Although it’s still *acre* everywhere, and some Americans still prefer the *meagre* spelling for the same reason.

Comment: Webster didn't change *-ize* to *-ise*. In his day *-ise* and *-ize* (and likewise, *-ization* and *-isation*) had been alternative spellings for some time, but *-ize* was the most popular in both Britain and America. Webster's decision to use the *-ize* form helped it remain the most popular form in the US, but then Johnson's dictionary also used *-ize* as does the OED to this day. Etymologically, the ending comes from two separate sources, Latin *-ize* and French *-ise* and the popularity of each has flipped over the centuries, with *-ise* making its last rise during the last century.